# Run JS as external file from DOS command to do URLencode

Tags: javascript, cmd, urlencode, url-encoding

Hi I got a macrorecorder tool (WinAut) that allow me to run Javascripts, Im using a JS to URLenconde some text string,  this is my JS...

```
var s = "%encStr%";

function urlencode(str) {
  str = (str + '').toString();
  return encodeURIComponent(str)
    .replace(/!/g, '\%21')
    .replace(/'/g, '\%27')
    .replace(/\(/g, '\%28')
    .replace(/\)/g, '\%29')
    .replace(/\*/g, '\%2A')
    .replace(/\%20/g, '+')
    .replace(/~/g, '\%7E');
}

WScript.Echo(urlencode(s));
```

Note that in the script I use the variable %encStr% to pass the string I want to encode from WinAut to JS, and JS return the enconded string as a variable. the script works fine if the JS is run directly in WinAut, but when I try to run the JS as an external file, calling it from the DOS command, I got a JS %25 issue which consist of...

the “RUN DOS Command” action’s “CommandOutput” result is “%25encStr%25″ (I guess is %encStr% converted), why?? it is supposed to convert the characters of the passed string (%encStr%), but instead it converts the characters of the %encStr% variable itself? why is this behavior?

These are the arguments of the DOS command that I use to run the JS

```
Cscript.exe //E:JScript //H:CScript //Nologo "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\JSurlEnc.js"
```

EDITED> This is what WinAutomation help says about running JS...

[image]

> Properties:
>
> Javascript to run:
>
> Enter here the Javascript code you want to execute. TIP: Within the
>   script, you may include WinAutomation variables, since they will be
>   evaluated prior to the Javascript code's execution. In the example
>   presented above, please remember to escape any backslash inside the
>   path variable (%DataDirectory%):
>
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64
>
> Store Output into:
>
> Enter the name for the variable to hold the script's output. A script
>   may write some text to the windows console during its execution. In
>   this case, all the text written by the script is stored into this
>   variable so that it can be processed by later actions.
>
> Store Error Output into:
>
> Enter the name for the variable to hold any errors that may occur
>   during the execution of the Javascript code.

Please hope some good fellow could give me advice. Thanks Advanced.

EDITED:
I added the Run DOS Command Action, it does not allow to add any variable. On WinAut forum link:
http://www.winautomation.com/community/topic/how-to-communicate-with-a-thirdapp-via-a-tcp-socket-in-winaut/page/2/#post-73510
(in post #23) they told me I could RUN JS script faster by running it from Run DOS Command Action, but I had to use some arguments in the Run DOS Command Action Properties Form, these...

```
Cscript.exe //E:JScript //H:CScript //Nologo "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\JSurlEnc.js"
```

but it doesn't work for me, please I would like to know what arguments I had to use, or in which way I have to modify the JS script in order to run it from "RUN DOS command" action.

Thanks Advanced.

[image]

Comment: Assuming  the value is being passed in an environment variable,  its value needs to be retrieved. See "ExpandEnvironmentStrings Method" in script56.chm for detailed documentation and examples. The help file is from  [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764)

Comment: Hi Traktor53 I downloaded the chm an look the chapter you suggested but is to ambigous, could you please give me a hint how to use it? the macrorecorder Im use is WinAutomation, and I tryint to pass a string variable to the CMD when running the JS as external file. How could I do it??? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Hi Natysiu16. I can help with how to pick up DOS environment string values, command line arguments or read standard input in  the script run by Cscript.exe. (If you want example code please ask and I'll post). What I don't know is how Winautomation passes a value to a javascript. Can you advise?

Comment: Hi @Traktor53 sorry, Im not shure about how Winautomation passes a value to a javascript, but I will upload what winaut help menu says about it, hope you could create script that catch winaut variables. I will edit the question. thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Run Javascript" and "Run DOS command" are two different actions.

The help quoted for Run Javascipt states that WinAutomation searches and replaces '%' quoted variables with their value in the action **before** calling Windows Script Host. This is talking about javascript entered in the input action field of the (job?) action editor within Winautomation.  It would not refer to searching and replacing the content of a script file accessed by a Run DOS command.  If the script can be run using the Run Javascript action it may be a better choice.

If the script must be run using the Run DOS action, the parameter string must be passed to it using a means that the script can pick up the value with. Typical DOS methods to do this are

1. Put the value into a named environment variable for the script to expand.
2. Pass the value using the standard input stream of the script. The input stream can be set using the '<' operator in the command line, or by using a pipe from the previous command
3. Pass the value as a command line argument.
4. Write the value to a text fie as an action and then have the script read it back from the file (similar to 2 using without using input redirection).

Presumably %variable% values can be expanded in WA DOS command action input field - something for you to look at.

For your interest a stript to report what it sees at run time. It uses a `C:\TEMP` folder, change as you wish.

File `test.js` in 'test.bat' below

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
function alert(str){ WshShell.Popup(str, 0, "Alert" , 64)};
function confirm( str){ return WshShell.Popup(str, 0, "Confirm", 33)==1;};

//        show input variable
var encStr = "%encStr%";  // also try without quotes to see if it works
alert("encStr: " + encStr);

//        show value of environment variable ENCSTR
alert( "ENCSTR is set to: " + WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ENCSTR%"));

//      show command line arguments passed to script
var s = "Command line arguments separated by commas: ";
var args = WScript.Arguments; // Call as a function, it's not an Array 
for( var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
{   s += (i ? "," : "") + args(i);
}
alert( s);

//    show first line of standard input (cscript.exe ONLY)
alert( WScript.StdIn.ReadLine());

//    Produce a dump of all environment variables if OK
if( confirm("Dump ALL environment variables to  C:\\TEMP\\set.txt?"))
    WshShell.run('cmd.exe /C SET>C:\\TEMP\\set.txt"');
```

File `test.bat` to demonstrate outside WA

```
Rem
Rem   Save as test.bat and run to demonstrate test.js using cscript.exe
Rem
SET ENCSTR="This is the value of environment variable ENCSTR"
ECHO "This is standard input" | cscript.exe test.js foo was here
```

Please also see the Winautomation forum question [Call script with parameters](http://www.winautomation.com/community/topic/call-script-with-parameters/). Good luck!

Comment: Hi Traktor53, thanks for your support. Yes, the help was talking about javascript entered in the input action field of the job action editor within Winautomation. Also, yes javascript can be run in winaut using the "run JS action", by placing the JS text in the action input. But someone said JS could run faster if it was directly called from Run CMD... this is the link http://www.winautomation.com/community/topic/how-to-communicate-with-a-thirdapp-via-a-tcp-socket-in-winaut/page/2/#post-73510 sorry I forgot to mention that. Pls take a look to the link, it explains it better. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid the overhead of running JS action creating a temporary file with your expanded vairable definitions by runing a DOS command and put the (windaut) variable value in arguments. This is like "foo,was,here' in the script posted. It it not a great idea if your variable values contain Unicode, at least without a lot of debugging!. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Traktor53, Could you please tell me how I got to put the winaut variable in the "Run DOS command" arguments? please take a look to my question, I added more important related info. I don't understand what arguments I got to use in the "Run DOS command" and/or in which way I have to modify the JS script in order to be called by the "Run DOS command" Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Hi @Traktor53, are you there?? pls help